# by_alias parameter on model_dump() is being ignored

Tags: python, pydantic, sqlmodel

In the following code, we see that the field `id` is indeed created with the alias of `user_id` when we print the `model_fields`.

However, when I then call `model_dump(alias=True)`, the returned dict has an `id` key, but does not have a `user_id` key as I am expecting.

Is this a bug, or is there something I am missing?

Maybe it is to do with `alias_priority=2`, but this doesn't seem to be a parameter in SQLModel's `Field`, only in Pydantic.

```py
from uuid import UUID, uuid4

from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


class Temp(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4, primary_key=True, alias="user_id")


t = Temp()

print(t.model_fields)
print(t.model_dump(by_alias=True))
```

Result:

```
{'id': FieldInfo(annotation=UUID, required=False, default_factory=uuid4, alias='user_id', alias_priority=2)}
{'id': UUID('1c8db668-be5c-4942-b494-ef69cbc0ef3a')}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of SQLModel you use?

It seems that alias broken since 0.0.14

https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/discussions/725

Comment: Wow, thanks! And 0.0.14 is when they upgraded to Pydantic v2, so downgrading to 0.0.13 is a big change.

Answer (score 0):

As @linpingta pointed out, the `by_alias` parameter is no longer working due to a bug in SQLModel.

As a fix, I have extended the `SQLModel` class an overridden the `model_dump()` method:

```py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel as SQLModelBase


class SQLModel(SQLModelBase):
    def model_dump(self, *args, **kwargs) -> dict[str, Any]:
        model_dump = super().model_dump(*args, **kwargs)

        if kwargs.get("by_alias") is False:
            return model_dump

        for field_name, field_info in self.__fields__.items():
            if field_info.alias:
                model_dump[field_info.alias] = model_dump.pop(field_name)

        return model_dump
```